# Trying to isert CDATA text into a xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [trying to insert CDATA section into a xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215573/trying-to-insert-cdata-section-into-a-xml)

I am trying to isert  into a xml but getting below error
 XSLT Error (javax.xml.transform.TransformerException): XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

input xml

```
 <Create>
 <requestXml>
 <ISD_XMLGateway>
  <Entity>HLR_ALC</Entity>
  <Origin>Comverse One</Origin>
  <Log_Level>0</Log_Level>
  <Params>
  <Param Name="HLR_System" Value="JT"/>
  <Param Name="HLR_ALC_Command" Value="Send_HLR_Command"/>
  <Param Name="HLR_Command"   Value="CRESBX:MSIN=Start43515213,MODEL=MODEL002,SNBSV=7797098765-TEL;"/>
     </Params>
                                         </ISD_XMLGateway>
                          </requestXml>
            </Create>
```

Output what i am expecting is

```
 <Create>
 <requestXml><![CDATA[
 <ISD_XMLGateway>
 <Entity>HLR_ALC</Entity>
 <Origin>Comverse One</Origin>
 <Log_Level>0</Log_Level>
 <Params>
  <Param Name="HLR_System" Value="JT"/>
  <Param Name="HLR_ALC_Command" Value="Send_HLR_Command"/>
   <Param Name="HLR_Command" Value="CRESBX:MSIN=Start43515213,MODEL=MODEL002,SNBSV=7797098765-TEL;"/>
   </Params>
   </ISD_XMLGateway>]]>
                          </requestXml>
            </Create>
```

in the XSL i have added the two text nodes after requestXml nodeas below
    `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
         <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>`

Answer (score 0):

This page seems to have the answer you're looking for:
http://www.bernzilla.com/2008/02/12/utilizing-cdata-section-elements-in-xsl/

Did you try the solution I proposed for your other formulation of this question?
[i want to replace > with &gt; for some of my nodes in my xml using xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126812/i-want-to-replace-with-gt-for-some-of-my-nodes-in-my-xml-using-xslt/14163310#14163310)

Answer (score 0):

Well outputting an element's content as a CDATA section is easy with the `cdata-section-elements` attribute on `xsl:output` but you also seem to want to serialize the nodes inside the `requestXml` element in the input XML to form the contents of the CDATA section. To serialize you either need to check whether your XSLT processor supports an extension doing that or you need to use an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet doing that, such as provided on http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/.

You can then import that stylesheet and use it as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:import href="xml-to-string.xsl"/>

<xsl:output method="xml" cdata-section-elements="requestXml"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="requestXml">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:call-template name="xml-to-string">
      <xsl:with-param name="node-set" select="node()"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That way the input

```
<Create>
 <requestXml>
 <ISD_XMLGateway>
  <Entity>HLR_ALC</Entity>
  <Origin>Comverse One</Origin>
  <Log_Level>0</Log_Level>
  <Params>
  <Param Name="HLR_System" Value="JT"/>
  <Param Name="HLR_ALC_Command" Value="Send_HLR_Command"/>
  <Param Name="HLR_Command"   Value="CRESBX:MSIN=Start43515213,MODEL=MODEL002,SNBSV=7797098765-TEL;"/>
     </Params>
                                         </ISD_XMLGateway>
                          </requestXml>
            </Create>
```

is transformed into the result

```
<Create>
 <requestXml><![CDATA[
 <ISD_XMLGateway>
  <Entity>HLR_ALC</Entity>
  <Origin>Comverse One</Origin>
  <Log_Level>0</Log_Level>
  <Params>
  <Param Name="HLR_System" Value="JT"/>
  <Param Name="HLR_ALC_Command" Value="Send_HLR_Command"/>
  <Param Name="HLR_Command" Value="CRESBX:MSIN=Start43515213,MODEL=MODEL002,SNBSV=7797098765-TEL;"/>
     </Params>
                                         </ISD_XMLGateway>
                          ]]></requestXml>
            </Create>
```