# trying to insert CDATA section into a xml

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

Hi I have added the below two xsl text nodes to get CDATA in my output xml

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"&gt;&lt;![CDATA[&lt;/xsl:text&gt;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"&gt;]]&gt;&lt;/xsl:text&gt;</xsl:text>
```

In My output i am getting the below

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</xsl:text>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]></xsl:text>
```

I want my output to be like

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
```

I am bit new to xslt/xml so any help will be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text> <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
```

If you want your output like the previous

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"&gt;&amp;lt;![CDATA[&lt;/xsl:text&gt;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"&gt;]]&amp;gt;&lt;/xsl:text&gt;</xsl:text>
```